# MOTU 828 mk2: How do you toggle +4dB/-10dB for each of the inputs from the front panel?

Tags: motu

Using MOTU's CueMix software, you can toggle +4dB/-10dB on each of the inputs (as well as "Boost"). I've figured out how to do just about everything else from the front panel of my 828mk2, but can't see how to toggle this setting.

Note that MOTU only provides documentation for the 828 Mk3 currently. It appears that the 828 Mk2 manual was available previously in hardcopy, but never in PDF format. I contacted MOTU, and they suggested I use the mk3 manual. Unfortunately, the front panel is different on the Mk2, so the Mk3 manual doesn't help.

My underlying problem is that I own synthesizers that range from balanced +4dB output to unbalanced -10dB. The unbalanced output is very quiet, and I often want to switch over to -10dB mode and possibly turn on "boost" without having to load another app on my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was chatting with [SF Logic Ninja (David Earl)](http://www.youtube.com/user/SFLogicNinja) and [Rob Michael](http://www.youtube.com/user/atmosmusic) earlier today, and it happens that we all have MOTU 828 mkII audio interfaces. David remembered that the param knob controls the +6dB and +4/-10 dB settings, so I gave that a try. No luck on my unit. Later, I opened my MOTU up, blew some canned air into it, and reassembled it. Now my MOTU front panel controls work properly - it was the param knob.

In short: When your 828 mkII is in mixer mode (display says `Gain`), turn the `param` knob to the right until it says `4/10`. That's the +4/-10 mode. Use the `cursor` and `value` knobs to select +4dB or -10dB for each input. Turn the `param` knob one more click to the right, and you get `+6dB`, which does exactly what it says, just like `4/10` mode.